# Adding a custom header to existing headers using Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring

How do I add a custom header to **outbound** requests?

Currently, I have a class that is:

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

public class MySecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements Filter {
```

The use case is:

1. I receive an **inbound** (someone, a client calls my app) request. I need to first extract one specific header and to perform some computations on this specific header key and value.
2. I need to invoke a third party API with an **outbound** request (this time, I am the client, I need to call another server) in order to get some values.

   As I invoke this third party API, this time, it is my turn to inject a custom header key value to the outbound request I am going to make.

   The reason I said "I inject" is because I am using a client library I have little control over, and the client library will send the HTTP request outbound.

Just to avoid confusion, step 1 and 2 are not related to each other, at least from a logic and algorithm point of view. I just detailed the steps (like I don't need to inject the header from step 1 into step 2 etc...)

Now, in order to perform step 2, I am using the well known

```java
final class MutableHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    // holds custom header and value mapping
    private final Map<String, String> customHeaders;

    public MutableHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        this.customHeaders = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
        this.customHeaders.put(name, value);
    }

    public String getHeader(String name) {
        // check the custom headers first
        String headerValue = customHeaders.get(name);

        if (headerValue != null) {
            return headerValue;
        }
        // else return from into the original wrapped object
        return ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getHeader(name);
    }

    public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
        // create a set of the custom header names
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(customHeaders.keySet());

        // now add the headers from the wrapped request object
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Enumeration<String> e = ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getHeaderNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            // add the names of the request headers into the list
            String n = e.nextElement();
            set.add(n);
        }

        // create an enumeration from the set and return
        return Collections.enumeration(set);
    }
}
```

This and other variations can be found online since 2016 I think.

I was wondering, since I am already using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in order to "filter/ intercept" inbound requests and verify custom header.

Is it possible to use similar to inject a custom header to an outbound request please?

I somehow have a feeling I am over complicating what I am currently doing, and that there might be a more elegant and efficient solution instead of `extends HttpServletRequestWrapper` +

```java
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String someImportantValue = computeSomeCustomeHeaderValue();
    MutableHttpServletRequest mutableRequest = new MutableHttpServletRequest(httpRequest);
    mutableRequest.addHeader("X-Some-Custom-Header", someImportantValue);
    chain.doFilter(mutableRequest, response);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be done using the `org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteIpFilter.XForwardedRequest`

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final String result            = getSomeNewHeader();
        final HttpServletRequest httpRequest       = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        final XForwardedRequest  xForwardedRequest = new XForwardedRequest(httpRequest);
        xForwardedRequest.setHeader("additionalHeader", httpRequest);
        chain.doFilter(xForwardedRequest, response);
    }
```

Without having to re write a wrapper again

Comment: "but not the outbound request" -> it does for outbound requests